# SDK Manager crashes

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu-14.04

I open android studio 1.0.1 using the following command

```
sudo ./studio.sh
```

installation goes well and I started adding sdk packages http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html
but whenever I try to run sdk manager, it places a prompt "Starting sdk manager" with a progress bar then after 2 or 3 seconds it closes.

Java Version:

```
java version "1.7.0_76"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_76-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.76-b04, mixed mode)
```

I have openjdk6 and openjdk7 as well but I use Oracle's Java because I start getting problems when I set those openjdk as the default.

I've searched for the log files through the idea.properties and found it. It is named idea.log under my home/user_name/.AndroidStudio/system/log directory and contains the following

```
2015-02-03 09:47:24,757 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2015-02-03 09:47:24,773 [     16]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: Android Studio (build #AI-135.1641136, 11 Dec 2014 00:00) 
2015-02-03 09:47:24,773 [     16]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Linux (3.13.0-44-generic, i386) 
2015-02-03 09:47:24,773 [     16]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.7.0_76-b13 (Oracle Corporation) 
2015-02-03 09:47:24,773 [     16]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 24.76-b04 (Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM) 
2015-02-03 09:47:24,837 [     80]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=250m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.boot.library.path= -Djna.debug_load=true -Djna.debug_load.jna=true -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false -XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd -Djb.vmOptionsFile=./studio.vmoptions -Xbootclasspath/a:./../lib/boot.jar -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio -Djb.restart.code=88 
2015-02-03 09:47:25,060 [    303]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library loaded (32-bit) in 223 ms 
2015-02-03 09:47:25,192 [    435]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - Snappy library loaded (1.0.5) in 102 ms 
2015-02-03 09:47:25,192 [    435]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - 2015-02-03 09:46:22 [Patch] Original patch does not exist: /tmp/jetbrains.patch.jar.androidstudio

2015-02-03 09:47:31,615 [   6858]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - WM detected: Mutter (Muffin) 
2015-02-03 09:47:33,561 [   8804]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor intellilang-python-support.xml 
2015-02-03 09:47:36,584 [  11827]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 21 plugins initialized in 4408 ms 
2015-02-03 09:47:36,601 [  11844]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: Android Support (10.1.0.1), CVS Integration (11), Commander (1.0.0), Copyright (8.1), Git Integration (8.1), GitHub, Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio (0.2.8), Google Login (1.0), Gradle, Groovy (9.0), I18n for Java, IDEA CORE, IntelliLang (8.0), JUnit (1.0), Maven Integration, Properties Support, Subversion Integration (1.1), Task Management (1.0), Terminal (0.1), TestNG-J (8.0), hg4idea (10.0) 
2015-02-03 09:47:41,914 [  17157]   INFO - ellij.vfs.persistent.FSRecords - Marking VFS as corrupted 
2015-02-03 09:47:41,918 [  17161]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=200; buffer=10; max=502530048 
2015-02-03 09:47:42,031 [  17274]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Starting file watcher: /home/ralf/android-studio/bin/fsnotifier 
2015-02-03 09:47:42,095 [  17338]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Native file watcher is operational. 
2015-02-03 09:47:42,302 [  17545]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/other.xml file is null 
2015-02-03 09:47:42,390 [  17633]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/project.default.xml file is null 
2015-02-03 09:47:42,732 [  17975]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/filetypes.xml file is null 
2015-02-03 09:47:43,630 [  18873]   INFO - .history.utils.LocalHistoryLog - local history version mismatch (was: 0, expected: 5), rebuilding... 
2015-02-03 09:47:43,630 [  18873]   INFO - .history.utils.LocalHistoryLog - FS has been rebuild, rebuilding local history... 
2015-02-03 09:47:43,710 [  18953]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/path.macros.xml file is null 
2015-02-03 09:47:43,718 [  18961]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/ui.lnf.xml file is null 
2015-02-03 09:47:43,757 [  19000]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/options.xml file is null 
2015-02-03 09:47:44,091 [  19334]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/notifications.xml file is null 
2015-02-03 09:47:44,113 [  19356]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/usage.statistics.xml file is null 
2015-02-03 09:47:44,118 [  19361]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/statistics.application.usages.xml file is null 
2015-02-03 09:47:45,344 [  20587]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/keymap.xml file is null 
2015-02-03 09:47:46,281 [  21524]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/window.manager.xml file is null 
2015-02-03 09:47:46,347 [  21590]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/abbreviations.xml file is null 
2015-02-03 09:47:46,531 [  21774]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/ide.general.xml file is null 
2015-02-03 09:47:51,350 [  26593]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/stubIndex.xml file is null 
2015-02-03 09:47:51,466 [  26709]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/editor.xml file is null 
2015-02-03 09:47:51,470 [  26713]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/macros.xml file is null 
2015-02-03 09:47:51,475 [  26718]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/quicklists.xml file is null 
2015-02-03 09:47:52,369 [  27612]   INFO - tellij.xml.Html5SchemaProvider - HTML5_SCHEMA_LOCATION = /home/ralf/android-studio/lib/idea.jar!/resources/html5-schema/html5.rnc 
2015-02-03 09:47:52,369 [  27612]   INFO - tellij.xml.Html5SchemaProvider - XHTML5_SCHEMA_LOCATION = /home/ralf/android-studio/lib/idea.jar!/resources/html5-schema/xhtml5.rnc 
2015-02-03 09:47:52,369 [  27612]   INFO - tellij.xml.Html5SchemaProvider - CHARS_DTD_LOCATION = /home/ralf/android-studio/lib/idea.jar!/resources/html5-schema/html5chars.ent 
2015-02-03 09:47:53,832 [  29075]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/colors.scheme.xml file is null 
2015-02-03 09:47:53,888 [  29131]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/editor.codeinsight.xml file is null 
2015-02-03 09:47:54,976 [  30219]   INFO -                  TestNG Runner - Create TestNG Template Configuration 
2015-02-03 09:47:55,374 [  30617]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 21 project components initialized in 2967 ms 
2015-02-03 09:47:55,375 [  30618]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 0 module(s) loaded in 0 ms 
2015-02-03 09:47:56,075 [  31318]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/jdk.table.xml file is null 
2015-02-03 09:47:56,250 [  31493]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/code.style.schemes.xml file is null 
2015-02-03 09:47:56,453 [  31696]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/debugger.renderers.xml file is null 
2015-02-03 09:47:56,485 [  31728]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/terminal.xml file is null 
2015-02-03 09:47:57,610 [  32853]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/studio.build.statistics.xml file is null 
2015-02-03 09:47:57,624 [  32867]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/androidStudioFirstRun.xml file is null 
2015-02-03 09:47:57,638 [  32881]   INFO - pl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl - 85 application components initialized in 20614 ms 
2015-02-03 09:47:57,681 [  32924]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - App initialization took 92269 ms 
2015-02-03 09:48:02,710 [  37953]   WARN - ateSettings.impl.UpdateChecker - Connection failed. Please check your network connection and try again. 
2015-02-03 09:48:19,965 [  55208]   INFO - droidStudioSpecificInitializer - Found Studio home directory at: '/home/ralf/android-studio' 
2015-02-03 09:48:19,965 [  55208]   INFO - droidStudioSpecificInitializer - Looking for Android SDK at '/home/ralf/android-studio/sdk' 
2015-02-03 09:48:19,966 [  55209]   INFO - droidStudioSpecificInitializer - Looking for Android SDK at '/home/ralf/sdk' 
2015-02-03 09:48:19,966 [  55209]   INFO - droidStudioSpecificInitializer - Unable to locate SDK within the Android studio installation. 
2015-02-03 09:48:19,966 [  55209]   INFO - droidStudioSpecificInitializer - Checking if ANDROID_HOME is set: 'ANDROID_HOME' is 'null' 
2015-02-03 09:48:19,966 [  55209]   INFO - droidStudioSpecificInitializer - Unable to locate last SDK used by Android tools 
2015-02-03 11:09:29,505 [4924748]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE SHUTDOWN ------------------------------------------------------ 
2015-02-03 11:09:29,653 [4924896]   WARN - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Watcher terminated with exit code 129 
2015-02-03 11:09:30,213 [4925456]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - START INDEX SHUTDOWN 
2015-02-03 11:09:30,261 [4925504]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - END INDEX SHUTDOWN 
2015-02-03 11:09:30,261 [4925504]   INFO - stubs.SerializationManagerImpl - START StubSerializationManager SHUTDOWN 
2015-02-03 11:09:30,261 [4925504]   INFO - stubs.SerializationManagerImpl - END StubSerializationManager SHUTDOWN 
2015-02-03 11:09:30,261 [4925504]   INFO - .history.utils.LocalHistoryLog - Purging local history... 
2015-02-03 11:09:30,335 [4925578]   INFO - .history.utils.LocalHistoryLog - Local history storage successfully closed. 
2015-02-03 11:09:30,335 [4925578]   INFO - newvfs.persistent.PersistentFS - VFS dispose started 
2015-02-03 11:09:30,336 [4925579]   INFO - newvfs.persistent.PersistentFS - VFS dispose completed 
2015-02-07 02:17:54,774 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2015-02-07 02:17:54,798 [     24]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: Android Studio (build #AI-135.1641136, 11 Dec 2014 00:00) 
2015-02-07 02:17:54,798 [     24]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Linux (3.13.0-45-generic, i386) 
2015-02-07 02:17:54,798 [     24]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.7.0_76-b13 (Oracle Corporation) 
2015-02-07 02:17:54,798 [     24]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 24.76-b04 (Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM) 
2015-02-07 02:17:54,801 [     27]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=250m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.boot.library.path= -Djna.debug_load=true -Djna.debug_load.jna=true -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false -XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd -Djb.vmOptionsFile=./studio.vmoptions -Xbootclasspath/a:./../lib/boot.jar -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio -Djb.restart.code=88 
2015-02-07 02:17:54,846 [     72]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library loaded (32-bit) in 45 ms 
2015-02-07 02:17:55,184 [    410]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - Snappy library loaded (1.0.5) in 338 ms 
2015-02-07 02:17:55,184 [    410]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - 2015-02-07 02:17:51 [Patch] Original patch does not exist: /tmp/jetbrains.patch.jar.androidstudio

2015-02-07 02:17:55,901 [   1127]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - WM detected: Mutter (Muffin) 
2015-02-07 02:17:57,768 [   2994]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor intellilang-python-support.xml 
2015-02-07 02:17:59,971 [   5197]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 21 plugins initialized in 3545 ms 
2015-02-07 02:17:59,972 [   5198]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: Android Support (10.1.0.1), CVS Integration (11), Commander (1.0.0), Copyright (8.1), Git Integration (8.1), GitHub, Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio (0.2.8), Google Login (1.0), Gradle, Groovy (9.0), I18n for Java, IDEA CORE, IntelliLang (8.0), JUnit (1.0), Maven Integration, Properties Support, Subversion Integration (1.1), Task Management (1.0), Terminal (0.1), TestNG-J (8.0), hg4idea (10.0) 
2015-02-07 02:18:01,856 [   7082]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=200; buffer=10; max=502530048 
2015-02-07 02:18:02,224 [   7450]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Starting file watcher: /home/ralf/android-studio/bin/fsnotifier 
2015-02-07 02:18:02,257 [   7483]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Native file watcher is operational. 
2015-02-07 02:18:03,195 [   8421]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/notifications.xml file is null 
2015-02-07 02:18:03,737 [   8963]   INFO - lij.diagnostic.DebugLogManager - Set DEBUG for the following categories: [] 
2015-02-07 02:18:04,251 [   9477]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/window.manager.xml file is null 
2015-02-07 02:18:05,364 [  10590]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/macros.xml file is null 
2015-02-07 02:18:05,371 [  10597]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/quicklists.xml file is null 
2015-02-07 02:18:06,051 [  11277]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/terminal.xml file is null 
2015-02-07 02:18:06,527 [  11753]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/studio.build.statistics.xml file is null 
2015-02-07 02:18:06,545 [  11771]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/androidStudioFirstRun.xml file is null 
2015-02-07 02:18:06,566 [  11792]   INFO - pl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl - 85 application components initialized in 6303 ms 
2015-02-07 02:18:06,614 [  11840]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - App initialization took 14088 ms 
2015-02-07 02:18:23,605 [  28831]   INFO - droidStudioSpecificInitializer - Found Studio home directory at: '/home/ralf/android-studio' 
2015-02-07 02:18:23,605 [  28831]   INFO - droidStudioSpecificInitializer - Looking for Android SDK at '/home/ralf/android-studio/sdk' 
2015-02-07 02:18:23,605 [  28831]   INFO - droidStudioSpecificInitializer - Looking for Android SDK at '/home/ralf/sdk' 
2015-02-07 02:18:23,605 [  28831]   INFO - droidStudioSpecificInitializer - Unable to locate SDK within the Android studio installation. 
2015-02-07 02:18:23,605 [  28831]   INFO - droidStudioSpecificInitializer - Checking if ANDROID_HOME is set: 'ANDROID_HOME' is 'null' 
2015-02-07 02:18:23,606 [  28832]   INFO - droidStudioSpecificInitializer - Unable to locate last SDK used by Android tools 
2015-02-07 02:18:24,401 [  29627]   INFO -                  TestNG Runner - Create TestNG Template Configuration 
2015-02-07 02:18:24,410 [  29636]   INFO -                  TestNG Runner - Create TestNG Template Configuration 
2015-02-07 02:18:24,499 [  29725]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 21 project components initialized in 561 ms 
2015-02-07 02:18:24,499 [  29725]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 0 module(s) loaded in 0 ms 
2015-02-07 02:19:52,421 [ 117647]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE SHUTDOWN ------------------------------------------------------ 
2015-02-07 02:19:52,435 [ 117661]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - START INDEX SHUTDOWN 
2015-02-07 02:19:52,463 [ 117689]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - END INDEX SHUTDOWN 
2015-02-07 02:19:52,471 [ 117697]   INFO - stubs.SerializationManagerImpl - START StubSerializationManager SHUTDOWN 
2015-02-07 02:19:52,471 [ 117697]   INFO - stubs.SerializationManagerImpl - END StubSerializationManager SHUTDOWN 
2015-02-07 02:19:52,471 [ 117697]   INFO - .history.utils.LocalHistoryLog - Purging local history... 
2015-02-07 02:19:52,480 [ 117706]   WARN - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Watcher terminated with exit code 130 
2015-02-07 02:19:52,485 [ 117711]   INFO - .history.utils.LocalHistoryLog - Local history storage successfully closed. 
2015-02-07 02:19:52,485 [ 117711]   INFO - newvfs.persistent.PersistentFS - VFS dispose started 
2015-02-07 02:19:52,504 [ 117730]   INFO - newvfs.persistent.PersistentFS - VFS dispose completed
```

Comment: any exception or log messages?

Comment: None at all. It immediately closes. I've been trying to figure out for a while on how to resolve it.

Comment: I am using pure IntelliJ not Android Studio but they should be the same. Try to open studio.properties (or idea.properties) and try to find a $idea.system.path. It should be something like ${user.home}/.IdeaIC/system. Go there and in the log directory you should see log files.

Comment: @Gaskoin I think I have found the log file. But I do not know how to fix these. Some documents are being labeled null.

Comment: The manager can behave like that when you do not specify JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Looking for Android SDK at '/home/ralf/android-studio/sdk' 
2015-02-03 09:48:19,966 [  55209]   INFO - droidStudioSpecificInitializer - Looking for Android SDK at '/home/ralf/sdk' 
2015-02-03 09:48:19,966 [  55209]   INFO - droidStudioSpecificInitializer - Unable to locate SDK within the Android studio installation. 
2015-02-03 09:48:19,966 [  55209]   INFO - droidStudioSpecificInitializer - Checking if ANDROID_HOME is set: 'ANDROID_HOME' is 'null'
```

Intellij cannot find your sdk location, you should introduce ANDROID_HOME environment variable that points to sdk